# How to use requirejs to load jQuery plugin intlTelInput?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs, amd, umd

The plugin in question is https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input. All script tags are inserted by `requirejs` properly, but I still can't use the plugin `intlTelInput`.

What am I missing?

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/Scripts/require",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min",
        // jquery plugins
        "intlTelInput": "/Scripts/jquery/plugin/intlTelInput-5.3.0.min"
    }
});

define(["jquery", "intlTelInput"], function ($, tel) {
    console.log(tel); // output: undefined
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, a jQuery plugin must be accessed via jQuery.

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/Scripts/require",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min",
        // jquery plugins
        "intlTelInput": "/Scripts/jquery/plugin/intlTelInput-5.3.0.min"
    }
});

define(["jquery", "intlTelInput"], function ($, tel) {
    console.log($().tel); // now it works
});
```